# Python, selecting a specific file

Tags: python-3.x

I need to select a specific file, after specifying the number of this file in "if"...

Instead of "MTS.txt " we need the full path to the selected file using a digit!

I have not found any information about this on the Internet. Perhaps he made up his request badly!

```
from email import message
from click import clear

import pywhatkit
import pyfiglet
import os
import time

directory = 'MTS/'
# files = os.listdir(directory)

f = True
while (f==True): 
    def main():
        os.system('CLS')

        # print(files)

        mtstxt = pyfiglet.figlet_format("Wa Helper", font = "smslant")
        print(mtstxt)
        def send_message_inst():
            mobile = '+7' + input(' Номер: +7')

            with os.scandir(directory) as files:
                for i, file in enumerate(files):
                    print('   ', i + 1, file.name)
            nof = os.listdir(path="MTS/")
            # print(len(nof))
            
            while True:

                tarif = int(input(' Вариант: '))
                if tarif >= 1 and tarif <= int(len(nof)):
                    msg = open("MTS.txt", encoding='UTF-8')
                    message = msg.read()
                    msg.close()
                    break

                else:
                    os.system('CLS')
                    print(mtstxt)
                    print(' Номер:', mobile)
                    with os.scandir(directory) as files:
                        for i, file in enumerate(files):
                            print('   ', i + 1, file.name)
                    print("\033[31m{}\033[0m".format(" Ошибка - неверный вариант!"))
                
            pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(phone_no=mobile, message=message)
        

        send_message_inst()
        os.system('CLS')
        sndtxt = pyfiglet.figlet_format("Sent!", font = "smslant")
        print(sndtxt)
        time.sleep(5)
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':    
        main()
    else:
        break
```

Comment: I am sorry, but the statement 'I need to select a specific file, after specifying the number of this file in "if"..."  makes no sense to me, can you provide an example of what yoiu are trying to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.